# Numbered lists don't work with line breaks

Tags: google-docs

Below is an image of my Google Doc. If I want to add a break (i.e. a paragraph format) to one of my numbered items, it breaks the numbering system, and refuses to continue the numbering.

Microsoft Word behavior is different, and allows breaks between numeric points.

[image: example]

My question is if I'm missing something, and if Google Docs does really allow breaks in numbered lists. I'm not too familiar with Google Docs, so it's possible I'm unaware of a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line preserves the numeric context.